# Store custom label and date in Contact

Tags: swift, contacts-framework

I'm trying to store a custom label and associated date in a Contact.  This is my code:

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
let customLabel = "Label"
let customDate = DateComponents(year:1980, month:1, day:1)
contact.dates.append(CNLabeledValue<DateComponents>(label:customLabel, value:customDate))
```

The resulting error (on the last line) is:

"Type 'DateComponents' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dates` property takes an array of `CNLabeledValue<NSDateComponents>`.

You need to adjust your code just a bit in the last line to use `NSDateComponents`:

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
let customLabel = "Label"
let customDate = DateComponents(year:1980, month:1, day:1)
contact.dates.append(CNLabeledValue<NSDateComponents>(label:customLabel, value:customDate as NSDateComponents))
```